# How to implement a trigger before saving values in a Django form?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have the following view in Django that allows users to save the activities based on a specific category (see below):

[image: Front end view]

Every time a new activity is created, it receives 5 points as it was defined in the model :

```
class Activity(models.model):
    CATEGORY = [('AUTOMATION','AUTOMATION'), ('TROUBLESHOOTING', 'TROUBLESHOOTING')]

    activity = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=140)
    type     = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=CATEGORY, default=ACTIVE)
    points   = models.Integerfield(default=5)
```

However, my intention is that every time a new activity is inserted then this one should receive 5 points while the previous activities increase their previous points by 5, so the latest activity always contains the lowest value of points while the oldest activity contains the highest value. Currently, I have tried to implement this logic in the code from below but I don't see any increase of points in the activities:

```
# views.py
def create_task(request):
    form_create = ActivityModelForm(request.POST or None)
    if form_create.is_valid():
        obj = form_create.save(commit=False) 
        obj.points = form_create.cleaned_data.get('points') + 5
        obj.save()
        form_create = ActivityModelForm()
    template_name = 'task/formActivity.html'
    context = {'form': form_create}
    return render(request, template_name, context)


 # forms.py
 class ActivityModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = Activity
         fields = ['activity', 'type', 'points']



 def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
     super(ActivityModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
     self.fields['activity'].required = True
     self.fields['points'].required=False
     self.fields['type'].required=False
```

How should I implement my logic in the view? A trigger should be generated before committing data into the db but I don't know how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#pre-save

You can define own receiver, which performs the manual logic before committing data into the database.

Or also you can override model's `save()` function or form's `create()` function but most likely you will need to implement this code:

```
# models.py
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

def update(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    qs = Activity.objects.filter(status='Type').order_by('-id')[1:]

    for activity in qs:
        activity.points = activity.points + 5

post_save.connect(update, sender=Task)
```